# Change elasticsearch serilog sink http content header

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, kibana, serilog

I'm trying to use the serilog elasticsearch sink to write some log to kibana.
According to the spec [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)
the content should be set to `application/x-ndjson` and since there are no specific option for setting the content type i've tried with `GlobalHeaders` but it has no effect and it is set to json.
I've changed the sample application to the following:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.Console(theme: SystemConsoleTheme.Literate)
            .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("http://elastic:changeme@localhost:9200")) // for the docker-compose implementation
            {
                ModifyConnectionSettings =
                    x => x.GlobalHeaders(new NameValueCollection { { "Content-Type", "application/x-ndjson" } }),
                BufferBaseFilename = "Text.txt",
                Period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                //BufferBaseFilename = "./buffer",
                RegisterTemplateFailure = RegisterTemplateRecovery.IndexAnyway,
                FailureCallback = e => Console.WriteLine("Unable to submit event " + e.MessageTemplate),
                EmitEventFailure = EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToSelfLog |
                                   EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToFailureSink |
                                   EmitEventFailureHandling.RaiseCallback,
                FailureSink = new FileSink("./failures.txt", new JsonFormatter(), null)
            })
            .CreateLogger();

            // Enable the selflog output
            SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);

            Log.Information("Hello, world!");

            int a = 10, b = 0;
            try {
                Log.Debug("Dividing {A} by {B}", a, b);
                Console.WriteLine(a / b);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.Error(ex, "Something went wrong");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Log.Error(new Exception($"Test error {i}"), "Test error {Error}", "TEst message");
            }
```

The api call does not return error but the logs are not present in kibana.
Am i doing something wrong, or it just cannot be configured, or I need to change something in the server?

Answer (score 0):

I hope following code helps identifying whats going wrong

```
ModifyConnectionSettings = x => x.OnRequestCompleted(ELKReqCompleted);

 void ELKReqCompleted(IApiCallDetails apiCallDetails)
        {
            //apiCallDetails.AuditTrail
            //apiCallDetails.DebugInformation

        }
```